# Angular - add app name to your angular app url

Tags: angular

By default, when you issue ng serve, the url to access your angular app is

http://localhost:4200

If my app is called myApp, how do I make this url be like

http://localhost:4200/myApp

Comment: Set `baseHref` to `/myApp` in `angular.json` under `builder.options`.

Comment: @rveerd Thank you, that works!  Can you provide your comment as an answer so I can accept it.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the "base href". This can be done through the [command-line option `--base-href`](https://angular.io/cli/build#options) or in `angular.json`.

You can set the option under `architect.build.options` if you want to use the same value both for building and for development. You can also set a different value just for `ng serve` under `architect.serve.options`.

Comment: Thank you, that works